# Generating areas of agglomerations in response to EUs proposed definition of "10 p.e per hectare or above"

Tags: qgis, heat-map

In regards to EUs proposed updated Urban Wastewater Treatment Directive, the definition of agglomeration is proposed to be areas of 10 p.e. (population equivalents) per hectare or above. ([page 36](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/resource.html?uri=cellar:fc078ec8-55f7-11ed-92ed-01aa75ed71a1.0001.02/DOC_1&format=PDF)).

I'm interested to see how this turns out for small villages. Considering that the population data is a point layer with a number of people per address/point, what would be the most correct way to calculate the population density in QGIS to be able to generate a polygon of the areas with 10 or more people per hectare? A heatmap?